# Javascript toggleclass close button still showing after menu is closed

Tags: javascript, html

### **I have the javascript here for menu toggle**

```
//navicon//
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon2').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
 });
```

### **Here is the html portion**

```
<header>
<div class="logo pull-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" title=""></a></div>
<div class="navigation pull-right">
<a href="JavaScript:Void(0);">
<div id="nav-icon2">
 <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
<nav>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 centered text-center">
<ul>
<li><a href="#top" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about-sec">About Design Mania</a></li>
<li><a href="#ser">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#cont">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

The problem is when i click the hamburger button the menu opens perfectly. I have the website as 1 page scroll. So when clicked on a menu item it goes to that portion perfectly. But still the X button is showing , when again clicked on it the hamburger button appearing and this time menu opens and the hamburger button is showing there , but selecting menu and going to specific portion is not a problem.

So the main problem is once it showing closing button while menu is closed and once showing hamburger while menu is opened and this continues. So everytime it needs 2 clicks to make it perfect.

### **Here is my menu toggle**

```
//menu-toggle//
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navigation").click(function(){
        $(".menu").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your div `#nav-icon2` is inside an anchor `a` you should prevent the default action :

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav-icon2').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, its not helping. The problem remain same. I have tried many things like

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon2').click(function(){
If ($(this).hasclass('open'))
{
$(this),removeClass('open');
}
else {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
}
    });
 });

Its also not working.